# How to append an excel file in java and using JRXlsExporter to write that file

Tags: java, excel, jasper-reports

I have an excel file and i want to add new data to the end of that file.
For this i use this method

```
public static void exportXLS(JasperPrint jasperPrint, String fileName) throws IOException, JRException{
        SimpleXlsReportConfiguration configuration = new SimpleXlsReportConfiguration();
        configuration.setOnePagePerSheet(true);
        configuration.setDetectCellType(true);
        configuration.setCollapseRowSpan(false);
        configuration.setWhitePageBackground(false);

        File file = new File(fileName+".xls");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file,true);

        JRXlsExporter exporterXLS = new JRXlsExporter();
        exporterXLS.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
        exporterXLS.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(fos)); 
        exporterXLS.setConfiguration(configuration);
        exporterXLS.exportReport();
    }
```

I have set true the append parameter of the FileOutputStream constructor, but still not working.
When I open the file i find just the new data but not the old one.